# Data transfer using sockets in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, communication

I have a huge problem with an android app. What i need to do is :

1) User A does something in the first phone 
2) User B receives the information and does something automatically

I'm trying to use sockets. I've been successful but the problem is user B has to first click a button to receive the event data, what i want is that things happen in B's app as soon as something happens in User a's device. (user b does not know when A does something, there should be no need to click a button)

A small tutorial on how to send data from one android phone to another would be very helpful. All i want is for the receiver to be get data automatically if there is something to get.

Answer (score 1):

What Type of data are you passing. if its a `String` you can use `BufferedReader`.
`BufferedReaderObject.read()` will wait until you send string. So keep this read in a thread.
After Reading perform whatever you need.

**EDIT** see sample below

```
 @Override
 public void run() 
 {
     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
     String yourString=br.readLine();
     //work with your string
 }
```

Comment: yeah strings, i'm passing strings

Comment: Then try this ,will be a better choice for u.

Comment: doesn't seem to be working, can you write me a mini tutorial or something please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do P2P, well, thats going to be difficult on Android. You can however, emulate it by using [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).